# why the "three strong theorems of Continuous functions" valid at a closed interval only?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

1)If f is continuous on [a,b] and f(a)<0<f(b), then there is some x in [a,b] such that f(x)= 0

2)If f is continuous on [a,b], then f is bounded above on [a,b], that is, there is some number N such that f(x)≤N for all x in [a,b]

3)If f is continuous on [a,b], then there is some number y in [a,b] such that f (y) > f (x) for all x in [a,b]

why [a,b] not (a,b)?

Comment: Consider $f : (0, 1) \to (1, \infty), f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $f$ is continuous on (0, 1) but is clearly not bounded above so (2) and (3) do not hold.

Comment: user1207607, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question. If you do not write what you tried to solve your exercise, moderators will close your post very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first doesn't even make sense as a useful claim, and possibly lacks a well-defined $f$. If we assume $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous only on $(a,b)$, then the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1, & x = a \\
1, & a < x < b \\
2, & x = b \end{cases}
$$
is certainly a counterexample. An argumentation for why this matters is a notion called "compactness:" $(a,b)$ is not compact whereas $[a,b]$ is.

(For simplicity and to avoid going too deep into the weeds, a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is "compact" if it is both closed and bounded. The image of a compact set under a continuous function is itself compact. In fact, the function $f$, being continuous on a compact set, is also called "uniformly continuous," a stronger and more useful type.)

---

For the second one, just consider $\tan(x)$ and think about it for a few moments.

---

The statement of the third is incorrect, you can only ensure that $f(y) \ge f(x)$, not $f(y) > f(x)$. Consider $\sin(x)$ over a sufficiently large interval for an example.

As for why this might not work for open intervals $(a,b)$, simply consider the function $f(x)=x$ on any such interval; you can prove by contradiction that $f$ will never attain a maximum value, for essentially the same reason that $(a,b)$ itself does not contain a largest number. (Suppose that $M$ is the largest number in $(a,b)$. Then $\frac{M+b}{2}$ is larger than than $M$, yet less than $b$ as, say, explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4749255/597568).)

Comment: Please, do not answer very low-quality questions.